# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'news_category' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
    <p>{{volunteer.news_category}}</p>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-card tappable (click)="goToVolunteerVoteDetail(volunteer)" style="width:26%" class="pin" 
          *ngFor="let volunteer of selectedVolunteer">
          <!-- <p>{{volunteer.news_category}}</p> -->

          <img src="{{volunteer.Preview_image1}}" height="100">
          <div *ngIf="volunteer.title" class="volunteer-title">
            <small>{{volunteer.title}}</small>
          </div>
          <div class="volunteer-title">{{volunteer.like_number}}分</div> <!-- 志愿者评选头像像素：505x505px -->

        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

It will showing below error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'news_category' of undefined

but if I changed  `<p{{volunteer.news_category}}</p>` to

```
<div *ngFor="let volunteer of selectedVolunteer">
   <p>{{volunteer.news_category}}</p>
</div>
```

error will disappear, but showing many **news_category** in stead.

I just want it to show only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all items of `selectedVolunteer` keep the same value of `news_category`, you can just display the first item's `news_category` and display/hide it based on length of `selectedVolunteer`.

```
<div *ngIf="selectedVolunteer?.length > 0">
  <p>{{selectedVolunteer[0].news_category}}</p>
</div>
```